# How to capture output of DML in teradata?

Tags: teradata

I want to capture output of Teradata DML query into a variable in a stored procedure. For example:

```
delete from emp;
```

I want the number of deleted records to go in to a variable which can be used for logging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the the manuals?

There's old style [`ACTIVITY_COUNT`](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_151K/ch04.109.21.html)

```
declare cnt int;
delete from emp;
set cnt = activity_count;
```

and Standard SQL's [`GET DIAGNOSTIC`](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_151K/ch06.111.138.html#ww13833981)

```
declare cnt int;
delete from emp;
get diagnostics cnt = row_count;
```